# Find first element matching condition in Swift array (e.g. EKSource)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, eventkit

I would like to find the first `EKSource` of type `EKSourceType.Local` with a "single"-line expression in Swift. Here is what I currently have:

```
let eventSourceForLocal = 
    eventStore.sources[eventStore.sources.map({ $0.sourceType })
        .indexOf(EKSourceType.Local)!]
```

Is there a better way of doing this (such as without mapping and/or with a generic version of `find`)?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's a version of `indexOf` that takes a predicate closure - use it to find the index of the first local source (if it exists), and then use that index on `eventStore.sources`:

```
if let index = eventStore.sources.indexOf({ $0.sourceType == .Local }) {
    let eventSourceForLocal = eventStore.sources[index]
}
```

Alternately, you could add a generic `find` method via an extension on `SequenceType`:

```
extension SequenceType {
    func find(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self.Generator.Element? {
        for element in self {
            if try predicate(element) {
                return element
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let eventSourceForLocal = eventStore.sources.find({ $0.sourceType == .Local })
```

(Why isn't this there already?)

Comment: i am not sure why, but maybe because "SequenceType makes no requirement on conforming types regarding whether they will be destructively "consumed" by iteration. To ensure non-destructive iteration, constrain your sequence to CollectionType."

Comment: also there is missing try part (predicate can throw)

Comment: @user3441734: Good catch on the `try`, fixed. All the sequence operations will consume a sequence (map, contains, etc), so I don't think that's it. indexOf works fine but is limited to collections.

Comment: I called mine `findFirst` because thats a bit more self documenting:)

Comment: @DanielGalasko Good news, Swift 3 now includes a `first(where:)` method on sequences that does just this.

Comment: thats great @NateCook !

Comment: Link to proposal https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0032-sequencetype-find.md

Answer (score 124):

Alternatively in Swift4 you could use:

```
let local = eventStore.sources.first {$0.sourceType == .Local}
```

Comment: In Swift4, that becomes: `let local = eventStore.sources.first {$0.sourceType == .Local}`

Comment: This is the correct answer, using `filter` then `first` is sub optimal because it forces worst case of `n` time complexity. That means that even after you find the element, filter will still loop through the rest of the array. `first(where:{})` short circuits traversal and breaks after it finds the first occurrence.

Answer (score 22):

I don't understand why you're using `map` at all. Why not use `filter`? You will then end up with all the local sources, but in actual fact there will probably be only one, or none, and you can readily find out by asking for the first one (it will be `nil` if there isn't one):

```
let local = eventStore.sources.filter{$0.sourceType == .Local}.first
```

Comment: While this is the most straight-forward solution, it has the disadvantage of always filtering the whole collection, even though it only needs the first matching element. I'm not advocating for premature optimization, but for large collections that might matter.

Comment: @DanielRinser I agree, I like Nate Cook's answer better.

Comment: IMO premature optimization doesn't even come into play here—avoiding completely unnecessary work is neither premature nor optimization.

Comment: So you make it

`let local = eventStore.sources.lazy.filter{$0.sourceType == .Local}.first`

Answer (score 21):

**Swift 4** solution that also handles the situation when there are no elements in your array that match your condition:

```
if let firstMatch = yourArray.first{$0.id == lookupId} {
  print("found it: \(firstMatch)")
} else {
  print("nothing found :(")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5** If you want to find out from Array of Model then speciyfy **$0.keyTofound** otherwise use **$0**

```
if let index = listArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == lookupId }) {
     print("Found at \(index)")
} else {
     print("Not found")
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Let's try something more functional:

```
let arr = [0,1,2,3]
let result = arr.lazy.map { print(""); return $0 }.first(where: { $0 == 2 })
print(result) // 3x  then 2
```

**Whats cool about this?**
You get access to element or i while you search. And it's functional.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3 you'll need to make a few small changes to Nate's answer above.  Here's the Swift 3 version:

```
public extension Sequence {
    func find(predicate: (Iterator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Iterator.Element? {
        for element in self {
            if try predicate(element) {
                return element
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Changes: `SequenceType` > `Sequence`, `Self.Generator.Element` > `Iterator.Element`